# Want to print date&time together in one text field in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a newbie to android and struggling to achieve this.

I want to select date and time and also wants to add the selected date and time in one textfield with this format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm.

I searched on this but couldn't find what I want to achieve.

any guidelines in terms of code or link would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: in Android We don't have both Date and Time Picker in same Dialog ,If you want to make both selection then you need make you Own Custom Dialog with help of this two.http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html and https://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

Comment: Ya mate thats what I thoght. but didn't want to go with this solution but seems to me that I have to go with it.

Comment: or may be you have  make  choice First DatePicker and then TimePicker dialog .

Answer (score 1):

you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) by which you can format the *Date*.

```
String format = "dd-MM-yyyy";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
System.out.println(sdf.format(yourdate));
```

Comment: But How am I suppose to select date? Like in iphone app I can use date picker in wich I can select both date and time from it and pass the selected date and time to desired text field.

Comment: By http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html you will get the date thenafter you can parse it in SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

use this you can your desired format

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

like this **May 17, 2012 12:03:09 PM**

Comment: Thanks RajaReaddy but the thing I don't want to select current date I want to select date and time frome date picker.

Comment: so convert those values into string and then pass that string into the formatted..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make Custom Date and Time Picker then you can see how in this they have make.[Android Date Slider](http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/)